# Can E2064 be disabled in Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, dcc32

I have the following sample code in my DUnitX test project that fails to compile. This sample code is scoped identically to code that compiles without errors in a very large VCL forms project. Both projects are using Delphi XE4, yet when I reference the source file that compiles successfully in the VCL project in my DUnitX unit test project, it fails with the same [E2064 left side cannot be assigned to](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/E2064_Left_side_cannot_be_assigned_to_%28Delphi%29) this code produces:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

type
  TTestRec = record
    A: string;
  end;

const
  AConstArray : array [0..1] of TTestRec = ( (A: '1'), (A: '2') );

procedure E2064Test;
begin
  {$J+}
  {$WRITEABLECONST ON}
  AConstArray[0].A := '3'; // error here
  AConstArray[1].A := '4'; // error here
  {$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
  {$J-}
end;

begin
end.
```

Is there a compiler switch or some other strange path/setting that I need to specify to get this code to compile for my DUnitX test project in XE4?

Comment: Just curious, since you are writing data into the array, why not declare the array as `var` instead of `const`?

Comment: Er, $WRITEABLECONST and $J are the same thing

Comment: Yes, David. Thanks for making sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [{$J+}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Writeable_typed_constants_%28Delphi%29). This compiles for me.

```
type
  TTestRec = record
    A: string;
  end;

const
  {$J+}
  AConstArray : array [0..1] of TTestRec = ( (A: '1'), (A: '2') );
  {$J-}

procedure E2064Test;
begin
  AConstArray[0].A := '3'; // error here
  AConstArray[1].A := '4'; // error here
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the very quick reply. I couldn't figure out the right terms to googlebing. Unfortunately, in my DUnitX project, it's still not compiling. I've tried both {$J+} and {$WRITEABLECONST ON}. I'll create a single console app and see if it behaves differently there. Again, I'm in XE4

Comment: I cannot get this to compile in XE4. I'm updating my question to have completely stand-alone code as a console project.

Comment: @JohnKaster I am using XE4. I had the directive in the wrong place. I first set the project options which made it work. The code above should now work.

Comment: Heh. I see you found the same answer I did (we must have been typing simultaneously). Crediting you with the win. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Graymatter, I found the place to set the switch.

Click the checkbox under:

```
Project options | Delphi compiler | Compiling | Syntax | Assignable types constants
```

Update: As graymatter points out, the compiler switches, if used, need to be where the symbol is declared, not accessed.

Comment: They are not ignored. They need to be around the constant, not the code accessing the constant as it relates to how the object is defined.

Comment: Gotcha. However, when the switch is on, they don't need to be there at all.

Comment: I also don't understand why you want to use writeable typed constants. These are an anachronism from the 20th century. Your are not expected to use this switch any more.